# "Nested" Visual Studio 2010 Web Applications

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, publishing

I have a Web Application that I regularly update and publish to my website.

I also have a `/projects` directory in various projects I'm working on. Some of these projects are Web Applications (or Web Sites) themselves.

Directory Structure is like this:

```
/www
    default.aspx
    /static...
    /bin...
    /etc...
    /projects
             /skynet <- web site
             /deathstar_OS <- web application
             /johnny_5 <- web site
```

What is the correct way to set something like this up for one-click-publishing? Right now, when I Publish the www application it will (try to) compile everything (including the web sites and applications) together and publish it (I have to publish via ftp, btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not including the a project's directory in the `/projects` directory as part of the main web application they are not overwritten when publishing the main application.

:-)